# Iframe with sticky header

Tags: css, iframe, sticky

I am looking for options to make the header inside an iframe to be sticky. If I scroll, the header should be sticky inside and only the content should scroll.

I have added position:sticky and top:0 for the header element, but that doesn't work.

Please let me know if any options to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dinesh, I'm looking for a similar solution. We are working in a content management system so we have no control over how the iFrame is rendered. I believe the issue we have is that the iFrame has scrolling="no". If that is the case, I believe there is no way to have a header or footer stay at the top or bottom of the screen when scrolling. They will be positioned at the top or bottom of the iFrame content. If my assumption is correct, it is that the viewport for the iFrame is not the visible browser window but the size of the iFrame. If scrolling is not set to no, it may be possible but I'm not certain.

If you find a resolution to this, please share so others may benefit. I may look to see if I can come up with a JavaScript solution but may choose not to go down that path.

Comment: We have used window.postmessage to send the scroll position of the parent window to an iframe. Once the message is received, we have set the postion of the element. we have to calculate the position manually in js and set it (I don't see any other option to make the element inside iframe sticky). Hope this helps, let me know if you need more information or any better solution than this. Thanks

Comment: You are just telling why it's not working. And you gave a solution for it about which you are certain.